# How to add/remove from reactjs element in onClick event

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, nodes

I can add array of object element by using `onClick` event. However, I need to remove array of object by using same `onClick` event.

```
state = {
  listofdata: []
}

dddd = (data) => {
  const d = [...this.state.listofdata]
  const t = d.push(data)

  this.setState({
    listofdata: d
  })
}

<div className="col-md-6">
  {data.map((item) => (<ul><li key={item.name} onClick={() => this.dddd(item)}><span className="plus">+</span>{item.name}</li></ul>))}
</div>
```

Here is my code , when I click on button , i can add array item , but i remove array item by using `onClick` event

Comment: To remove an item, you need to have onClick call a function that updates the array in your state. When React detects a change in the state, it will refresh the display accordingly.

Comment: can you share hint code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thanks everyone. This is answer of toggle elements . 
you can add and remove clicking same button 
dddd = (selectedItem) => {
  const { listofdata } = this.state;

  const newList = [ ...listofdata ];

  const itemIndex = newList.findIndex(item => item.name === selectedItem.name);

  if (itemIndex > -1) {
    newList.splice(itemIndex, 1);
  } else {
    newList.push(selectedItem);
  }

  this.setState({
    listofdata: newList,
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the same `dddd` method both insert and remove (if it's already there), you can do use the `splice` function of `Array` like this:

```
dddd = (data) => {
  const d = [...this.state.listofdata]
  let index = -1
  // See if 'data' is already in the list
  for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) { 
    if (d[i].key === data.key) {  // See if you found 'data' in the list
      index = i; 
      break;
    } 
  }  
  if (index >= 0) {
    d.splice(index,1)              // Remove it from the array if present
  } else {
    d.push(data)                   // Push it if it wasn't there
  }
  this.setState({
    listofdata: d                  // Store the adjusted list
  })
}
```

where `data.key` is a way to compare the input object and the ones in the list.

Comment: I can only add item , it doesn’t work when I click on dd() method

Comment: what type of object is the `data`?  If it's a complex object them using `indexOf` may not match it.  If that's the case you'll need to write a function to find an existing value in the array like this:
```for (let i=0; i<d.length; i++) { 
  if (d[i].key === data.key)  
    {index = i; 
     break;} 
}```
where `key` is some part of the object that will let you compare them. I've edited the answer to include this change